Factorizations not sharing digits with original number
The sequence A371862 is "Positive integers that can be written as the product of two or more other integers, none of which uses any of the digits in the number itself."
In the extended sequence, some entries have nine of the ten digits. For example
909543680129861140820205019889143 = 7^39 would be in the sequence.
What are the smallest numbers in A371862 which have nine of the ten digits? Some of the smaller values I've found:
1476395008 = 22 2^26
505627938816 = 444444 4444 4^4
640532803911 = 777777 7^7

You should stress the fact that you consider base 10 representation. it would be interesting to ask the same question for other bases.

I see no problem with the focus on base $10$ in contrary to some other users. Many concepts were extensively studied although they were base-dependent. But it is not quite clear whether you just want to find the smallest such entry or to find the smallest , say , $100$ entries.

@Peter It is not a problem : just a precision ; for example, in the title "digits" should be replaced by "base-10 digits"
